# Could not build an app with pyinstaller: "Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories" although the app runs without problem from the script

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

So I wrote a simple "hello world" app with PyQt5 and am trying to build a standalone application with `PyInstaller`. I cd the directory where the app reside and run the app with `python hello_world.py` without problem. I then tried to build the app with `PyInstaller hello_world.py` and got the following error message. What should I do?

```
PyInstaller hello_world.py
46 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
46 INFO: Python: 3.7.1
46 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0
93 INFO: wrote T:\app\hello_world.spec
109 INFO: UPX is not available.
266 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['T:\\app', 'T:\\app']
266 INFO: checking Analysis
266 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
266 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
344 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
344 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
9250 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
9265 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
9875 INFO: Caching module hooks...
9890 INFO: Analyzing T:\app\hello_world.py
10125 INFO: Loading module hooks...
10125 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
12094 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
12094 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
14000 WARNING: Hidden import "PyQt5.sip" not found!
14000 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
14062 WARNING: Unable to find Qt5 translations C:/qt64/qt_1544645195969/_h_env/Library/translations\qtbase_*.qm. These translations were not packaged.
14062 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\i0310451\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 500, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 410, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 377, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 736, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py", line 11, in <module>
    hiddenimports, binaries, datas = add_qt5_dependencies(__file__)
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 514, in add_qt5_dependencies
    more_binaries = qt_plugins_binaries(plugin, namespace=namespace)
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 132, in qt_plugins_binaries
    pdir = qt_plugins_dir(namespace=namespace)
  File "c:\users\i0310451\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 117, in qt_plugins_dir
    """.format(namespace, ", ".join(paths)))
Exception:
            Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories
            Paths checked: C:/qt64/qt_1544645195969/_h_env/Library/plugins
```

Answer (score 1):

So I had to uninstall Anaconda and install Python 3.7.2 and PyInstaller and it worked